# Looking for formulas for my beginners c++ program

Tags: c++

So I am working on a program from a pearson book and we are to write a code that lets you input N exercises and then the scores for those exercises. I found a loop that works and terminates when I want it to but the final line of code adds up all the points earned and all the possible points.
I have no clue what the formulas are for the total points earned and total points possible are, I tried: totalPoints = pointsEarned + pointsEarned;

totalPointsPossible = pointsPossible + pointsPossible;

but this formula only adds the first 2 exercises. Do I need to write another loop that will add pointsEarned N times any help would be much appreciated.
This is my loop in case it helps:

```
while (N > 0 && J <= N)
{
    cout << "Enter the score received for Exercise " << J << ": ";
    cin >> pointsEarned;
    cout << "Enter the total points possible for Exercise " << J << ": ";
    cin >> pointsPossible;
    J++;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need variables that hold total points earned and total points possible that you add these input values to.

Comment: so I have totalPoints as a variable and totalPointsPossible as a variable. do they need to go inside the loop?

Comment: *"I found a loop that works"* -- you might benefit more from writing your own code than participating in [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) (i.e. copying code without understanding it). Just a tip. You are certainly free to disregard it or consider it off-base.

Comment: @Kreeych *"so I have totalPoints as a variable and totalPointsPossible as a variable."* -- Please add their definitions to your [mre]. Otherwise, they might as well not exist.

Comment: @JaMiT will do next time sorry I am brand new to this. Also I guess i should not say I found a loop, I did come up with this loop myself and apparently a for statement would be better. I am only on chapter 2 of this class and we have only covered if/else, while and do/while.

Comment: @Kreeych *"will do next time"* -- why wait for next time? You can still make this time better. Improving your question is the reason there is an "[Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73674730/edit)" link made available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sum up the total points earned and the total points possible.

Example:

```cpp
int pointsEarned, totalPointsEarned = 0;
int pointsPossible, totalPointsPossible = 0;

for (int J = 1; J <= N; ++J) {
    std::cout << "Enter the score received for Exercise " << J << ": ";
    if (!(std::cin >> pointsEarned)) break; // if input fails, break out
    
    std::cout << "Enter the total points possible for Exercise " << J << ": ";
    if(!(std::cin >> pointsPossible)) break;

    // sum up the totals:
    // the below is short for: totalPointsEarned = totalPointsEarned + pointsEarned
    totalPointsEarned += pointsEarned;
    totalPointsPossible += pointsPossible;
}
std::cout << "You got " << totalPointsEarned << " out of "
          << totalPointsPossible << '\n';
```